# Variable is not an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

when i try use in_array function in php for the second time for same array variable i got the following error saying:

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

when i wrap the function in condition is_array, it returns false, i already print the variable using print_r and its showing array structure, here's the code:

```
    $chosenCour = array();
    $chosenServ = array();
    foreach ($preferences as $preference) {
              if(!in_array($preference['courier'],$chosenCour)){
                $chosenCour[] = $preference['courier'];
              }
              if(!in_array($preference['courier_service'],$chosenServ)){
                $chosenServ[]= $preference['courier_service'];
              }
            }
foreach ($couriers as $courier) {
    $courCond = false;
                if(is_array($chosenCour)){
                  if(in_array($courier['courier_id'],$chosenCour)){
                    $courCond = true;
                  }
                }
}
```

Comment: **Definition:** `in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )` - meaning, you define what you wanna search first, and then set the desired array, not the other way around, like you do `in_array($preference['courier'],$chosenCour)`

Comment: @DainisAbols the first time i use in_array there is no problem with that, but for the second time, my variable that i want to reused is not recognized as an array even in is_array function

Answer (score 0):

Check the additional condition for non empty array

```
foreach ($couriers as $courier) {
    $courCond = false;
                if(is_array($chosenCour) && count($chosenCour) > 0){
                  if(in_array($courier['courier_id'],$chosenCour)){
                    $courCond = true;
                  }
                }
}
```